# How to hide text below an image in html?

Tags: html, css

Here is my site: http://bankloan.com-credit.info/freescore/limitedtime/lp1/001.php

If you make the browser window smaller (around 750x550) you will see that the pop up image is cluttered over the main text. What I need is for that pop up to not be cluttered.

I don't know much about code. I just used a WYSIWYG editor. I've been messing with it for hours and can't fix it.

I'm pretty sure it has something to do with the absolute positioning code that my program uses.

Answer (score 1):

If you need the `#message` popup to always be on top, you can set a high `z-index` value on the `div` e.g. `z-index: 9999`

In the case of your site you seem to be using inline stlyes, so you would need to add it as shown below.

```
<div id="message" style="z-index:9999; font-family: arial; position: absolute; top: 16px; left: 318px; margin-left: -300px; background-image: url('images/alert.jpg'); background-repeat: no-repeat; margin-top: -15px; margin-bottom: 4px; width: 562px; height: 131px; font-size: 12px;" onclick="javascript: document.getElementById('message').style.display = 'none';" onmouseover="document.body.style.cursor='pointer'" onmouseout="document.body.style.cursor='default'">
```